# Sample Random Effects from Mixed-effects Model

Tags: mixed-model, sampling, covariance-matrix

I have a mixed effects model that I'd like to simulate random effects from using a MVN approximation (sampling from the predictive distribution). My question is what is the advantage of simulating random effects by 1) simulating both fixed and random effects using the joint variance-covariance matrix (then just plucking out the random effects) or 2) simulating random effects conditioned on the fixed effects? I guess strategy #1 incorporates uncertainty in both fixed and random effects, while strategy #2 only incorporates the random effects variability. Anything else?

Rationale: Inside the mixed-effects model I'm making predictions that are random effects and I'd like to simulate different realizations of those predictions from the fitted model.

Comment: Have you seen or used the `merTools` package? It does exactly what you want and you can compare the two approaches. https://github.com/jknowles/merTools

Comment: Thanks, @ErikRuzek! I don't use ```lme4```, but I'll take a look at that and ```merTools```.